# Using offset(); coordinates to trigger fadeOut();

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, offset

You can tell by my rep that I'm a super novice, apologies if this seems simple to you.

I've got a model solar system spinning around in HTML and CSS. I've cobbled some JS in there to make the planets play some music and fadeOut() on hover()

However, I want to remove the hover() and make the planets do their thing based on their coordinates; each of them playing a note when they hit a certain coordinate.

I've tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = $("#mercury").offset;
if(x.top >= 1200.00 && x.left >=1000.00){
    $("#mercury").fadeOut("slow");

};
```

But, nothing happens.

I'm sure this is an issue of my own ignorance, I'm probably writing this incorrectly but, I need help.

In short, how do I trigger an event based on offset() coordinates?

Comment: Change `offset` to `offset()`

Answer (score 0):

To call a function you need to have parentheses after function name. So you need to change .offset to .offset(). Also you have if conditions closing curly bracket missing. So try to always indent your code, so you will see the opening and closing brackets.

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = $("#mercury").offset();
    if(x.top >= 1200.00 && x.left >= 1000.00){
        $("#mercury").fadeOut("slow");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an animation run loop? (A function that is constantly called to update your interface).

You are executing your code in the 'document ready' function. This function will execute only 'once' when your page has finished loading and never again.

To achieve what you want, you will need to continually execute your code so it does this check for each animation frame (as your animations are happening).

If you don't already have a run loop to put your code in, you could set a interval so its constantly checking the planets position.

*An example*

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var myLoop = window.setInterval(function() {

       var x = $("#mercury").offset();
       if(x.top >= 1200.00 && x.left >= 1000.00){
           $("#mercury").fadeOut("slow");
       }

    }, 200); // Execute the above every 200 milliseconds
});
```

If down the track you wanted to stop the checking/loop just execute:

```
window.clearTimeout(myLoop);
```